Rendering data on Mapbox using geojson-vt
I see similiar questions were asked but could find a definite answer.
I'm using Mapbox-gl with Vue3 (v-mapbox) and trying to render a lot of data.
One solution that i've found is mapboxs geojson-vt library.
Its seems to convert geojson to vector tiles on the fly but not sure how it eventually renders on the map as a layer.
So i need to get from here
const geojsonvt = geojsonVt(...some_geo_json...)

To here
mapboxMapInstance.addSource(some_source_extracted) (maybe type:vector??)
mapboxMapInstance.addLayer(...)

I saw its possible via demo that the author of this library published but not sure how to implement myself.
Thank you in advance
